# gcloud command - gcloud preview app modules get-logs mymodule --version=1 \ ~/log_file.txt doesn't work

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to get the gcloud log files to see an error I get when I try deploying my app to GCP. I looked at the docs and found the command `gcloud preview app modules get-logs mymodule --version=1 \ ~/log_file.txt` which is supposed to 'have logs saved to a file instead of being printed to standard out by specifying a file name'.

When I run the command I get the following error message:

```
Roberts-MBP:wikisite Robert$ gcloud preview app modules get-logs mymodule --version=1 \ ~/log_file.txt
usage: gcloud preview app modules get-logs  MODULE  [OUTPUT_FILE] --version VERSION [optional flags]
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.modules.get-logs) unrecognized arguments:  ~/log_file.txt
```

Am i running the command wrong? or do I need to make the log_file.txt file first or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `gcloud preview app modules get-logs mymodule ~/log_file.txt --version=1`

Comment: It made the file but its empty. Do you know why it might be empty?

Comment: Is `mymodule` a "standard" app, or a Managed VM/Flexible Environment app (ex. uses Docker builds)? `get-logs` only works with "standard" App Engine apps; we're working on new commands for Docker apps. You can check your logs in the [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) instead.